# Popup Javascript only

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a popup with input text only using JavaScript?

I have to create a popup like a prompt

```
var email = prompt("Texts1", "Email");

        if(email === null ) {
            return;
        }
(...) //something get the value from email
```

My problem is the Texts1 in prompt is too long and the window can't show it all. I can only use/change JavaScript (nothing in HTML!).

Comment: Think about what 'too long' means exactly.

Comment: you can use \n to break it onto the next line. Or create a modal which emulates the same behaviour as a prompt like how bootstrap or jqueryui does it.

Comment: use a div and in it use a <p> or a textarea... have them display:none and change that with js

Comment: Texts1 >= 30 chars. Using prompt the texts doesn't show at complete (only 20ish)

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be javascript only? If you want more control over how the popup works and looks you can create a simple html dialog and only show it when necessary.

You cannot edit the way the native javascript prompts / alerts appear.

Comment: Thats a comment, not an answer

Comment: because it said so.. i can only use JS nothing else

Comment: @Jonasw I think the last line makes it count as an answer.

Comment: @JohnJohn: You have to realise that javascript can insert **anything** into HTML. So there is no need for "no html" because that does not make sense at all. If a solution requires you to have `<form id=foo></form>` just do `document.body.innerHTML += "<form id=foo></form>"` (or even better, use document.createElement and document.body.appendchild, but that's not strictly necessary)

Comment: @JohnJohn, To come up with a better solution then "It cannot be done" I asked a question to see if further assistance could be brought to you. As well as giving you an alternative option that would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use pop-ups you can break the line with `\n` which might help you. But in my opinion you will be more satisfied with using so called "modals". Modal is something like a pop-up, written in HTML. You are able to show it whenever you need. It's just simple HTML like:

```
<div id="modal-1">
    <form>
        <!-- your form input etc. -->
    </form>
</div>
```

which you can trigger with CSS (the example is using centered position):

```
#modal-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

If you have this ready, you can trigger it with any event you need by just modifying the `document.getElementById('modal-2').style.display = 'block';` inside your event's callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `hidden div` with the text that you want to show on some event like if email field is empty with pure JavaScript like:

**EDIT**

If you can't change html then you can show multile js alert like

```
alert("Hello! This is the way to \n add line breaks to an alert box");
```

**End Edit**

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {

var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
       modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Email field is empty</p>
  </div>

</div>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="email">
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It isnt possible. You need html, however you can make it independent of the sites content:

```
function ask(question,callback){
  var container=document.createElement("div");
container.textContent=question;
var field=document.createElement("textarea");
container.appendChild(field);
var ok=document.createElement("button");
container.appendChild(ok);
ok.onclick=function(){
  callback(field.value);
};
document.body.appendChild(container);
return {container:container,field:field,ok:ok};
}
```

Use like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  //make shure the js is executed after the page is loaded completely
  var question=ask("whats your name?",function(name){
    alert(name);
  });
```

You can add custom styles:

```
question.container.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

However, this isnt sync as prompt(), so the callback is needed. Hope it helps...